# Updated Vscodium breaks jupyter extension - webview issue?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, vscodium

I need to run jupyter scripts for my thesis project and the vscodium-bin aur update vscodium-bin 1.78.1.23130-1
breaks the jupyter extension. I have tried downgrading the jupyter extension version but that doesn't fix the issue. I have also tried adding the jupyter.renderer extension to the workplace trust but that didn't work

```
ERR Extension 'ms-toolsai.jupyter' wants API proposal 'notebookControllerKind' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
workbench.desktop.main.js:624  INFO [perf] Render performance baseline is 42ms
index.html:16 Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'sha256-N4YFn5ze5crjPqMK/opogKs7bSGWtf3lmjV/3LfbSOs=' 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-gL9sMIYaOSpgU2r/kGAnB4ETLEykloodzKO0BgrHHPQ='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.
```

^ are the errors returned in the debug mode but I don't have enough experience with the extensions to figure out exactly what this means. I am looking at downgrading the vscodium package but was hoping there was another method for fixing the problem.

From the debugging errors it seems to be a webview problem with the 'content security policy' as the effected element is:

```
<iframe name="b99df735-9077-4cee-a1f7-3f8752179ac0" class="webview " sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-downloads" allow="cross-origin-isolated; autoplay; clipboard-read; clipboard-write" src="vscode-webview://0oh9eumbe6e1khin571jfquekro0lhhg08al92ragmj1v4ape05f/index.html?id=b99df735-9077-4cee-a1f7-3f8752179ac0&amp;origin=a412a15a-3d65-4fce-9614-7f70111786e3&amp;swVersion=4&amp;extensionId=&amp;platform=electron&amp;vscode-resource-base-authority=vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net&amp;parentOrigin=vscode-file%3A%2F%2Fvscode-app&amp;purpose=notebookRenderer" style="border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: auto;"></iframe>
```

[image: error msg that state content security policy blocks inline execution of scripts and stylesheets]

Comment: see bug report on github: https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/1508